# How to setup multiple apps with yeoman angular and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am building an app with rails-api as backend and angularjs as frontend. I came across yeoman angular for scaffolding. Now in my angularjs, i need separate layout for frontend and admin. So I thought i can create to apps with yeoman. But problem is
1)it creates separate grunt files and separate servers for both apps
2) myapp/ should redirect to frontend app and myapp/admin should redirect to admin app

How do i have a common grunt server for both apps which will communicate with rails server?

Comment: found any answer to that ?